# Calculate average td in each tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow

I want to calculate average `class='dtb'` with the input `.toan`, `.ly`, `.hoa` in each table row.

[My fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ndh2311/ytr5npvm/8/)

**Problems:** It just calculating the first table row then put the result to orther rows below instead of calcuting in each table row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#outputtable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
        var toan = parseInt($('.toan').html());
        var ly = parseInt($('.ly').html());
        var hoa = parseInt($('.hoa').html());
        var dtb = ((toan + ly + hoa) / 3);
        $(this).find('.dtb').html(dtb.toFixed(1));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change from here:

```
$('#outputtable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
  var tr = $(this);

  var toan = +tr.find('.toan').text();
  var ly = +tr.find('.ly').text();
  var hoa = +tr.find('.hoa').text();
  var dtb = (toan + ly + hoa) / 3;

  tr.find('.dtb').html(dtb.toFixed(1));
});
```

Using `$(this)` inside *each* function (in this case), it would assign to current `tr` element. From this element, you find an element which has a class with the name `toan` - `ly` - `hoa`.

To get the text inside each `td` tag, you just need to use `.text()` method (no need to use `.html()` method).

To convert a string to a number (in your case), you can just use

```
+$(this).find('.toan').text();
```

no need to use `parseInt` method. It's better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the instance of each of the input classes within the row

`$('.toan').html()` will always return value of first element of that class found in the whole page

Instead use `find()`

```
var toan = parseInt($(this).find('.toan').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndh2311/ytr5npvm/8/) code,

Change this code of appending table line

```
 $("#outputtable").find("tbody:last").append("<tr><td>"+ stt +"</td><td class='ten'>"+_ten+"</td><td class='toan'>"+_toan+"</td><td class='ly'>"+_ly+"</td><td class='hoa'>"+_hoa+"</td><td class='dtb'>?</td></tr>");
```

To:

```
$("#outputtable").append("<tr><td>"+ stt +"</td><td class='ten'>"+_ten+"</td><td class='toan'>"+_toan+"</td><td class='ly'>"+_ly+"</td><td class='hoa'>"+_hoa+"</td><td class='dtb'>?</td></tr>");
```

And this code of average calculation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#outputtable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
        var toan = parseInt($(this).find('.toan').html());
        var ly = parseInt($(this).find('.ly').html());
        var hoa = parseInt($(this).find('.hoa').html());
        var dtb = ((toan + ly + hoa) / 3);
        $(this).find('.dtb').html(dtb.toFixed(1));
    });
});
```

To:

```
    $("#tinhdtb").on('click', () => {
         $('#outputtable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
    debugger;
        var toan = parseInt($(this).find('.toan').html());
        var ly = parseInt($(this).find('.ly').html());
        var hoa = parseInt($(this).find('.hoa').html());
        var dtb = ((toan + ly + hoa) / 3);
        $(this).find('.dtb').html(dtb.toFixed(1));

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Akshay Bhalerao, but i think don't need to change the appending table line, just change the code of average calculation is ok.

Comment: Just give it a try